# Generate md5 checksum scala js

Tags: md5, scala.js, webjars

I am trying to calculate hex md5 checksum at in scala js incrementally. The checksum will be verified at server side once file is transferred.

I tried using [spark-md5](https://github.com/satazor/js-spark-md5) scala js web jar dependency:

> libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.webjars.npm" % "spark-md5" % "2.0.2")
>
> jsDependencies += "org.webjars.npm" % "spark-md5" % "2.0.2" / "spark-md5.js"

scala js Code:-

```
val reader =  new FileReader
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data)  // data is javascript blob object
val spark = scala.scalajs.js.Dynamic.global.SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer
reader.onload = (e: Event) => {
   spark.prototype.append(e.target)
   print("Checksum - > " + spark.end)
}
```

Error:-

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined
>       at Object.SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer.append (sampleapp-jsdeps.js:596)
>       at FileReader. (SampleApp.scala:458)

I tried google but most of the help is available are for javascript, couldn't find anything on how to use this library in scala js.

Sorry If I missed something very obvious, I am new to both javascript & scala js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From spark-md5 readme, I read:

```
var spark = new SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer();
spark.append(e.target.result);
var hexHash = spark.end();
```

The way you translate that in Scala.js is as follows (assuming you want to do it the dynamically typed way):

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js
import scala.scalajs.js.typedarray._
import org.scalajs.dom.{FileReader, Event}

val SparkMD5 = js.Dynamic.global.SparkMD5
val spark = js.Dynamic.newInstance(SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer)()
val fileContent = e.target.asInstanceOf[FileReader].result.asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer]
spark.append(fileContent)
val hexHashDyn = spark.end()
val hexHash = hexHashDyn.asInstanceOf[String]
```

Integrating that with your code snippet yields:

```scala
val reader =  new FileReader
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data)  // data is javascript blob object
val SparkMD5 = js.Dynamic.global.SparkMD5
val spark = js.Dynamic.newInstance(SparkMD5)()
reader.onload = (e: Event) => {
   val fileContent = e.target.asInstanceOf[FileReader].result.asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer]
   spark.append(fileContent)
   print("Checksum - > " + spark.end().asInstanceOf[String])
}
```

If that's the only use of `SparkMD5` in your codebase, you can stop there. If you plan to use it several times, you should probably define a facade type for the APIs you want to use:

```scala
import scala.scalajs.js.annotation._

@js.native
object SparkMD5 extends js.Object {
  @js.native
  class ArrayBuffer() extends js.Object {
    def append(chunk: js.typedarray.ArrayBuffer): Unit = js.native
    def end(raw: Boolean = false): String = js.native
  }
}
```

which you can then use much more naturally as:

```scala
val reader =  new FileReader
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(data)  // data is javascript blob object
val spark = new SparkMD5.ArrayBuffer()
reader.onload = (e: Event) => {
   val fileContent = e.target.asInstanceOf[FileReader].result.asInstanceOf[ArrayBuffer]
   spark.append(fileContent)
   print("Checksum - > " + spark.end())
}
```

Disclaimer: not tested. It might need small adaptations here and there.

Comment: Thanks @sjrd. This is awesome!